# Make POST without form under browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it any way to make post request without using form (I need to put pure JSON in Post body) by a browser?

It is possibly with async request, but what's about sync POST ?

Comment: if jQuery : [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: @PranavKapoor If jQuery can do this, then pure JS can do it too.

Comment: @Magus : I know that. Thus a comment and not an answer

Comment: Meet `XMLHTTPRequest()`...

Answer (score 3):

Using jQuery's `.post()` function will send a post request to a page and get it's results for you.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

It's also possible to use `.ajax()` or just use pure javascript to send an Ajax request (XMLHTTPREQUEST).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Of course, if you don't want to use XML, then you can follow the answer to: [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit), it will give you more insight on the  matter.

Comment: Yes, But I want make a new request. And I want to make a new request(go to new page)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Try this -

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST","test.html",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: Yes......In JavaScript, XMLHttpRequest is used to send Ajax request which is async request.